# pthread execution on linux

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I started doing pthread programming on linux and at the very first programme i got totally confused. Below is the programme I am running

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *print_message_function( void *ptr );

int main(){
 pthread_t thread1, thread2;
 char *message1 = "Thread 1";
 char *message2 = "Thread 2";
 int  iret1, iret2;

/* Create independent threads each of which will execute function */

 iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);
 iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);

 /* Wait till threads are complete before main continues. Unless we  */
 /* wait we run the risk of executing an exit which will terminate   */
 /* the process and all threads before the threads have completed.   */

 pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
 printf("amit");
 pthread_join( thread2, NULL); 

 printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",iret1);
 printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",iret2);
 exit(0);
}

void *print_message_function( void *ptr ){
 char *message;
 message = (char *) ptr;
 printf("%s \n", message);
}
```

First one thing i would like to know is order of thread execution is not sequential ??

Second thing is i intensionally put print("amit"); to see main is really halt during thread1 getting terminated but in the output what we can see is printf statement is executed first. The output of whole process is

Thread 1

Thread 2

amitThread 1 returns: 0

Thread 2 returns: 0

Comment: "is order of thread execution is not sequential".  That's correct.  If you find that surprising enough to ask here, please step away from the code and find a book multi-threaded programming.  Please read the book all the way through.  You might look for a good tutorial before writing more-or-less random code.  The subject is quite complex and not the kind of thing to be explored haphazardly.  https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: Is that really the output? It outputs `ajay` instead of `amit`? What's your question?

Comment: Thansk @Lott ,i think i need to learn basics first...

Comment: nd one more thing on different machine am getting different o/p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First one thing i would like to know is order of thread execution is not sequential ?

Not normally.  Threads on most modern operating systems (early threading implementations on Linux used cooperative multitasking) execute in parallel and the order in which your `printf`s get executed is partially non deterministic.  The `pthread_join`s impose some ordering on things, so:

- `Thread 1` must come before `Amit` because the main thread waits for thread 1 to finish before printing `Amit1`
- `Thread 2` must come before `Thread 1 returns:` because of the second `pthread_join`.  All of the `printf`s in `main` appear in the order they appear in `main`.

I hope that answers your question.  I'm not entirely sure what you were asking but feel free to ask for clarification on any point.

Comment: but only thing i got confused is why printf("amit"); gets executed before pthread_join( thread1, NULL); ,is it expected??

Comment: @AMIT: the `printf("amit")` line does not get called before the `pthread_join(thread, NULL)` according to the output you posted.

Answer (score 13):

You are right in saying that the *order of thread execution is not sequential*. To some extent, that is the whole point of using threads, i.e. to run other tasks concurrently.

The output you are seeing is as expected, and can possibly be different.

Perhaps this will help:

```
   main            thread1     thread2
    |                
    |--create--------+-----------\
    |                |           |   
    |            "Thread 1"      |   "Thread 2" can
    |                |           |<- occur anywhere
    |               /            |   along this line
   join(1) ---------             |
    |                            |
    |                            |
  "amit"                         |
    |                            |
    |                            |
   join(2) ---------------------/
    |
    |
"Thread 1 returns"
"Thread 2 returns"
    |
  exit(0)
```

The only guarantee you have is:

- "`Thread 1`" will always be printed before "`amit`" (because `pthread_join()` waits for thread 1 to end before the main program can proceed)
- "`Thread X returns ...`" statements will always come at the end, after both threads have terminated.