# When does the routine passed to pthread_create start?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

Given the following code

```
#include <pthread.h>

void *pt_routine(void *arg)
{
    pthread_t *tid;
    tid = (pthread_t *) arg;
    /* do something with tid , say printf?*/
    /*
    printf("The thread ID is %lu\n", *tid);
    */
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc;
    pthread_t tid;
    rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, pt_routine, &tid);
    if (rc)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    printf("The new thread is %lu\n", tid);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Can the routine ALWAYS get the right `tid`?

Of course I could use pthread to fetch self ID but I just wonder when does the routine run.

Comment: "When does the routine passed to pthread_create start?", after the call to `pthread_create()` ? Your question is unclear. "Can the routine ALWAYS get the right tid?" what do you mean ?

Comment: You're passing `&tid` as both the first argument of `pthread_create` (the place where `pthread_create` should store the new thread's ID) and the fourth argument of `pthread_create` (an argument to be passed into `pt_routine`).  It *sounds* like you're asking whether it's possible for `pt_routine` to run and dereference its `arg` before `pthread_create` has actually stored the thread's ID at that address.  Is that correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pthread execution on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991470/pthread-execution-on-linux), [Pthread Run a thread right after it's creation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12536649/608639), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there are actually 2 questions:

- which thread will execute first
- will the thread id be saved *before* the new thread starts.

This answer concerns Linux, as I don't have any other platforms available. The answer to the first question can be found [in the manuals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

> Unless  real-time
>          scheduling   policies  are  being  employed,  after  a  call  to
>          `pthread_create()`, it is indeterminate which thread—the caller or
>          the new thread—will next execute.

So it is clear that in your case, it is indeterminate which thread will actually run first. Now, another question is how is `pthread_create` implemented - if it could somehow create a dormant thread, storing its id first, and then later starting it?

Well, linux creates the new thread using the `clone` system call:

```
clone(child_stack=0x7f7b35031ff0, 
      flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM
          |CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID,
      parent_tidptr=0x7f7b350329d0,
      tls=0x7f7b35032700,
      child_tidptr=0x7f7b350329d0) = 24009
```

Now, it seems that the thread id is stored with a pointer from the `clone` call, but it seems clear that `child_tidptr` doesn't refer to the *address of* `tid`, as if I print it, the the address is different; this is some internal variable within the `pthread` library; and `tid` would be updated *after* the `clone` system call returns in the parent thread.

And indeed, [`pthread_self`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html) says the following:

> The thread ID returned by `pthread_self()` is not the  same  thing
>          as the kernel thread ID returned by a call to `gettid(2)`.

This confirms that the kernel thread ids are distinct from `pthread_t`s

Thus, in addition to this not being supported by the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html), there is no such guarantee on the Linux platform in practice - the `tid` will need to be set in the **parent thread** after `clone` returns, otherwise the *parent* wouldn't immediately know the thread id of the child - but this also means that if the child is the first to execute after the return, then the thread id might not be set there yet.

Answer (score 2):

`pt_thread()` will begin execution at some arbitrary point after `pthread_create()` is called - and that includes that it might start running before `pthread_create()` returns to the calling code. And there is no guarantee made that the `pthread_create()` implementation will update the `tid` variable before the thread starts execution.

So there is nothing in your code that ensures that `pt_routine()` will read the `tid` value properly.  You would need to use some sort of synchronization to ensure that occurs properly without a data race. Or you could have the thread call `pthread_self()`.

See the "Application Usage" section of [the POSIX spec for `pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html):

> There is no requirement on the implementation that the ID of the created thread be available before the newly created thread starts executing. The calling thread can obtain the ID of the created thread through the return value of the pthread_create() function, and the newly created thread can obtain its ID by a call to `pthread_self`

Comment: Another [quote](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) from linux man page: "See pthread_self(3) for further information on the thread ID returned in *thread by pthread_create().  Unless real-time scheduling policies are being employed, after a call to pthread_create(), it is indeterminate which thread—the caller or the new thread—will next execute."